# Web Service Jquery Call has xml data but success gives null

Tags: jquery, xml, web-services, json

I have used:

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = true)]
```

My web service call result is:

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
[{_pkId:"",_code:"",_message:"The file has been uploaded successfully.",_status:"1"}]
</string>
```

on jquery success:

```
success: function (xmlHttpRequest, status) {
                    alert("success");
                    alert("data: " + xmlHttpRequest);
```

...

I get:

```
success
null
```

I tried best to find why i get null and set appropriate headers too. I dont know even I can see the response in Firebug but success function alerts null.
Any help much appriciated.

Comment: you have response type `json` and you want xml as output?

Comment: please post some relevant code of your web service

Comment: I could see the response in firebug returned from my asmx web service.

Comment: In jquery success it alerts success and then for data it alerts null. I am not specific about data format since i can see the response in firebug but in jquery it say null.

Comment: what `dataType` have you set in the ajax request?

Answer (score 0):

```
on jquery success:

success: function (status) {
            alert(status);
         }
```